# KVM: Win10-Guest without internet connection

Tags: ubuntu, kvm

i set up a Windows10 guest on a ubuntu server (hetzner-cloud.server, root access) with kvm/virsh. virtual machine is running fine and i can connect via VNC. Thing is, that the windows 10 guest has no internet connection and i am stuggeling to figure out why.

Here is what i got:

interface from virsh edit win10-virt

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:XX:XX:XX'/>
  <source bridge='br0'/>
  <model type='rtl8139'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

command brctl show

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.901b0edacc31   yes     enp0s31f6 vnet0
virbr0      8000.5254000a6103   yes     virbr0-nic
```

content of /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      match:
        macaddress: 90:1b:0e:XX:XX:XX
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      macaddress: 90:1b:0e:XX:XX:XX
      interfaces:
        - enp0s31f6
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - XX.XX.XX.130/32
        - HOST-IPV6/64
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: XX.XX.XX.129
          on-link: true
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 213.133.99.99
          - 213.133.100.100
          - 213.133.98.98
          - 2a01:4f8:0:1::add:1010
          - 2a01:4f8:0:1::add:9898
          - 2a01:4f8:0:1::add:9999
```

arp -n

```
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
XX.XX.XX.129             ether   00:31:46:0d:XX:XX   C                     br0
```

/etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

within windows10 the network settings are set to dhcp.

Did i miss some configuration or made a mistake? got no glue right now. may you can help me, thanks.

Comment: So is there a DHCP server in your LAN? Since you are doing static on the host.

Comment: Also can the VM reach other hosts in your LAN like `XX.XX.XX.129`? Or is it actually a "WAN LAN"? (i.e. you are directly attached to your ISP)

Comment: ah i forgot: this is a hetzner-cloud server (root, ubuntu)

Comment: Same difference. Are you even getting any IP assigned by DHCP on the VM (make sure you know that IPv4 link-local addresses are not from a DHCP server...).